# AngularJS - Conditional attribute not working with variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Below is my Angular Controller

**Angular JS**

```
var multistage = angular.module("multistage", []);

multistage.controller('groupStanding', function($scope1) {
    $scope1.grouplimit = 3;
    $scope1.competitorDTL = <?php echo json_encode($competitorDtl); ?>;
    console.log($scope1.grouplimit);
});
```

and this is my html code below ...

**HTML**

```
    <tbody data-ng-controller="fixtureController">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="comp in competitorDTL">
        <td>
          <span class="badge" data-ng-if="$index+1 <= grouplimit">        
          {{$index+1}}</span> {{ comp.name}}
       </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Its not working and i am unable to identify exactly what the problem is? If I replace grouplimit variable and put 3 directly there than its work fine.

Comment: it should be `multistage.grouplimit` in the html.

Comment: Assuming you're using the right controller, give a shot to `{{grouplimit}}`.

Comment: Sir, multistage.grouplimit also not worked ..

Comment: there is already another controller @Karim

Comment: @user7192960 partial is bound to diff. controller

Comment: @Valberthe it also not printing this value there as well as on console also ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller name is `'groupStanding'` and you have used `data-ng-controller="fixtureController"` change it to `data-ng-controller="groupStanding"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{{groupelimit}}
```

`groupelimit` will then be replaced by its value in the corresponding controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed '{' in `{$index+1}}`

```
<td><span class="badge" data-ng-if="$index+1 <= grouplimit">{$index+1}}</span>{{ comp.name}}
```

That could be the reason

Comment: my array element is printing fine with the $scope1 variable then why do i need $scope in place of $scope1?

Comment: Sorry, actually that i have mistaken here while writing the question . but the problem still exists.